# How to curl data from website hosted by host from ssh client?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, docker, curl

I didn't found an answer to my question and hope it's not an duplicate.

I'm hosting a website on my windows host on localhost:23456. From my host PC I can curl data using:

```
curl localhost:23456/topic1
```

Now I want to achieve the same from my connected linux system. There are connected through local wifi hotspot from my host pc. My pc has the IP 192.168.137.1 and my linux system 192.168.137.100.
I'm able to connect to my linux computer via ssh using:

```
ssh linux@192.138.137.100
```

What doesnt work is the following curl command from my linux system:

```
curl 192.138.137.1:23456/topic1
```

Further I want to access the same webpage from inside of an docker container on my linux IP. But I think, since the network is bridged, it must be the same curl command as from my linux system?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `23456` port on windows not exposed yet, you can try scan it with `nmap` or other scanning tools to make sure on it.

If the output show `filtered` you need to allow `23456` port on windows host firewall.